# ExpressJS JSON to CSV

Tags: node.js, express

I have this ExpressJS code that I am working with. My application sends an array of _id's which I search for and grab from mongo. I am then trying to generate a CSV of the data returned. The code below is working as expected. It is writing the CSV to the root directory of my application. The modification I am wanting to make is that I want the file to download to the users machine. I have been googling this topic for quite some time now and everyone says that in order to download a file you need to use `fs.createWriteStream` or `res.download()` however I dont know how to implement it with my current method structure. Obviously it needs to happen inside `json2csv()` after the csv is created. Id rather not have to write the file, stream, then delete. Id like it if I could just stream.

The json2csv package I am using is here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

```
router.post('/Equipment/Report', function(req, res, next) {
    var filteredData = req.body;
    console.log(filteredData);
    Equipment.find({_id: { $in: filteredData }}, function(err, Equipment) {
        console.log(Equipment);
        var fields = ['ClassPrefix', 'UnitNumber'];
        json2csv({ data: Equipment, fields: fields}, function(err, csv) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('file saved');
            });
        });
    });
    //console.log(filteredData);
});
```

EDIT to suggested code -

```
router.post('/Equipment/Report', function(req, res, next) {
    var filteredData = req.body;
    console.log(filteredData);
    Equipment.find({_id: { $in: filteredData }}, function(err, Equipment) {
        console.log(Equipment);
        var fields = ['ClassPrefix', 'UnitNumber'];
        json2csv({ data: Equipment, fields: fields}, function(err, csv) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log(csv);
            res.attachment('data.csv');
            res.send(csv);
        });
    });
});
```

This does not download any file. 
Logs a response of 200.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code snippet instead of the `writeFile`

```
res.attachment('file.csv');
res.send(csv)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I replaced your code for fs.writeFile and nothing happened.

Comment: any advice in where to go from here, I updated with current code. Still not working

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to write the string to a file on disk first, just use [`res.attachment()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.attachment) and then write the `csv` string to the response:

```
router.post('/Equipment/Report', function(req, res, next) {
  var filteredData = req.body;
  Equipment.find({_id: { $in: filteredData }}, function(err, Equipment) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.statusCode = 500;
      return res.end(err.message);
    }
    var fields = ['ClassPrefix', 'UnitNumber'];
    json2csv({ data: Equipment, fields: fields}, function(err, csv) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.statusCode = 500;
        return res.end(err.message);
      }
      res.attachment('data.csv');
      res.end(csv);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I replaced fs.writeFile with your code and nothing happened.

Comment: also, Im guessing you meant res.send();

Comment: `res.send()` is more or less a wrapper for `res.end()`. Can you explain what you mean by "nothing happened?" Are some callbacks not being executed or ?

Comment: the application didn't crash. I noticed no changes in the logs. No file was downloaded.

Comment: If you put a `console.log()` inside each callback (route handler, mongo, json2csv), are each of them called or just some or none at all?

Comment: route handler gets logged. mongo return gets logged. csv gets logged, then POST with status of 200 is logged.

Comment: If I reinsert the writeFile, no POST response of 200 is logged

Comment: obviously because I have no res. duh. my bad. By route handler being logged I meant my first log of the filteredData

Comment: Any other ideas for debugging

Answer (score 2):

I think, you want to download the csv file on the browser and so, you need not create a file on the server side.

You need to set the response content type correctly, for browser to treat it as a downloadable link.

```
json2csv({ data: Equipment, fields: fields}, function(err, csvStr) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.statusCode = 500;
    return res.end(err.message);
  }
  res.header("Content-Disposition",attachment;filename=data.csv"); 
  res.type("text/csv");
  res.send(200, csvStr);
})
```

Comment: doesn't the res.Attachment() suggestion that the others made do exactly that? Set the headers?

Answer (score 0):

That is something you can do on the client side. You should send the data to the client and make the browser download the csv file on client browser.

```
//Inside your server router
json2csv({ data: Equipment, fields: fields}, function(err, csv) {
  if (err) {
    next(err);
  }
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.csv');
      res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
      res.send(csv);
});
```

On the client side, make the browser download it.

```
window.open(requestedUrl);
```